# Google Chrome: Permanently allow local file to download multiple files

Tags: google-chrome, filesystems

I have a program with this local file path:
`C:/Users/n.herwich/Documents/Entwicklung/Software/javascript_wip/tagconfig/src_folderpicker/tagconfig.htm`

The program has a button that downloads two files at once. When I click it, chrome asks me for the following permission:

"This file wants to Download multiple files"

I give the permission, but chrome keeps asking every time I click the button again despite not reloading the site.

I tried adding the file path to the files that can download multiple files but that doesn't change anything.

[image: chrome-permission]

Is it somehow possible to use regex in the URL declaration?

Is there a chrome extension that gives the permission to everything?

I'm running out of ideas

Edit: I just ended up using firefox. There is no such prompt when downloading multiple files.

Comment: Go to `chrome://settings/`, Security and Privacy, Site Settings, Additional permissions, Automatic downloads, and in "Allowed to automatically download multiple f‌iles" try to Add localhost.

Comment: Just "localhost" doesnt work

Comment: Try to emulate the other settings that are already there, so probably `file:///C:/Users/n.herwich` or try specifying more or less of the entire path.

Comment: Tried that. Nothing I did worked, but maybe I'm missing something